# setting up a servlet on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Im very VERY new to web development, and im trying to make an servlet with java. I have figured out how to setup a apache tomcat server. Now, the server has the following file structure:

```
tomcat6:
       -work
            -Catalina
                 -localhost
                       -_
            -catalina.policy
       -webapps
            -ROOT
                 -META-INF
                 -index.html
       -shared
            -classes
       -server
            -classes
       -logs
            -localhost.2012-05-19.log
            -catalina.out
            -catalina.2012-05-19.log
       -conf
            -policy.d
                 -lots of .policy files
            -catalina
                 -localhost
                      -ROOT.xml
            -web.xml
            -tomcat-useres.xml
            -server.xml
            -logging.pproperties
            -context.xml
            -pcatalina.properties
       -common
            -classes
```

I just edited a aouto-generated servlet in NetBeans, and within the IDE it works fine, but nom matter where i put it on my tomcat server, i get a 404, or it just tries to download the .class file.

Where should I put the classto make it work?

Comment: woops, the linebreaks didn't kick in the way I wanted. I hope it'll still make some kind of sense :)

Comment: I do not know where you got this tree from but this is not Tomcat 6. There are no `shared` or `common` directories. There is only `lib`.

Comment: It looks like there's a number of spelling mistakes in the above. (pcatalina.properties, tomcat-useres.xml) Are those accurate reflections of the contents of the file system?

As Michael points out, this is not a Tomcat 6 file tree - does Netbeans really put catalina.policy in tomcat/work?

policy.d is not a standard Tomcat directory either.

Comment: I figured out that netbeans uses glassfish and not tomcat. The spelling mistakes are all mine.

The tree is how the tomcat was setup just after installation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build a WAR file and then put the warfile into the webapps directory.

Comment: How does one make a WAR? can netbeans build it?

Comment: A bit of googling will serve you well here. There are tons of tutorials, probably some for netbeans at all.

Comment: You don't have to build a WAR (though it's certainly more convenient).  You could just put the files down in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell tomcat that your webapp has servlets, what classes implement the servlets, and what URL paths the servlets are mapped to.  This is done in `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

First you need to define the servlet in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.myapp.servlets.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Then you need to map the servlet (by its `servlet-name`) to a URL path, also in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Assuming you have tomcat listening on port 8080, if you go to

```
http://your.tomcat.host:8080/webappname/HelloWorld
```

you will hit the servlet.

Note that `HelloWorldServlet` is arbitrary text.  It could be anything and doesn't have to be related to the class name or the URL path (though it's useful for it to be similar to them).  What matters is that you use the same string in the `servlet-name` tag in both the `servlet` tag and in the `servlet-mapping` tag.

To write a servlet you need to need to implement the `Servlet` interface.  **However** you very seldom do that directly.  Instead, you (most commonly) extend `HttpServlet` and override one or more of the `doXXX()` methods.  If you're not writing a HTTP-based servlet you extend `GenericServlet` and override the `service()` method.  Other libraries beyond the Servlet API may provide other protocol-specific servlet base classes you can extend.

Comment: Typo: should be </url-pattern> not </servlet-name>

Comment: Also, how would the servlet class itself be implemented? What should it extend, and which methods must be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually doing it without any IDE then this is the Structure

```
 Apache Tomcat folder --> wep-app folder --> your_web_app_name --> WEB-INF,.html,.jsp 
                                                                      |
                                                                      |--> classes
                                                                      |
                                                                      |--> lib
                                                                      |
                                                                      |--> web.xml (Description Descriptor)
```